# Android project suddenly full of errors because of different supporting librarys

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook-android-sdk

So i wanted to add a facebook SDK to my android projects, the outcome was this:

[image]

I've decided to "undo" changes first so i removed the facebook library from my project
after:

[image]

The error is "R cannot be resolved", if im importing android's R it wont recognise the layouts anymore
for example:
[image]

My libs are:

[image]

I've tried removing support v4/v13 but neither helped. Im clueless, please help.

Answer (score 1):

Copy/Paste the same latest v4 library in all the projects,

Comment: Can you explain further? I have 1 project that contains same sort of errors in multiple classes

Comment: In your project and it's dependency projects you must have the same support-v4 file. Now clean and build your project and dependencies, problem should be gone.

Comment: Cleaning and building didnt help. Ive got errors in the project